# Why is an integer comparison changing my query's join type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a query based on two tables with a navigation property between them:

```
// idOrder shared between classes as nav property
public partial class OrderItem
{
    public int idOrder { get; set; }
    public int idInventory { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public partial class Order
{           
    public Nullable<short> idSite { get; set; }
    public int idOrder { get; set; }            
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> genDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

When I run a query against them, it appears to work fine with the expected inner join:

```
var orderItems = dbc.orderItems
                 .Where(oi => oi.Order.genDate > lastWeek)
                 .Select(oi => oi.idInventory);
```

returns the inner joined query

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[idInventory] AS [idInventory]
FROM  [dbo].[Order_ITEMS] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[idOrder] = [Extent2].[idOrder]
WHERE [Extent2].[genDate] > @p__linq__0
```

However, if I instead run a very similar query

```
var orderItems = dbc.orderItems
                 .Where(oi => oi.Order.idSite == 1234)
                 .Select(oi => oi.idInventory);
```

instead I get this extemely expensive outer join query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[idInventory] AS [idInventory]
FROM  [dbo].[Order_ITEMS] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[idOrder] = [Extent2].[idOrder]
WHERE  CAST( [Extent2].[idSite] AS int) = @p__linq__0
```

I believe this is because idSite is nullable, but in this case I'm not asking to return the null sites, so outer joining doesn't seem useful here. Why is this change causing the query to change its join type, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: If you have the `idOrder` on the `OrderItem`, why are you using the navigation property to look up the `Order.idOrder`?. `var orderItems = dbc.orderItems.Where(oi => oi.idOrder == 1234)`

Comment: Sorry, typo'd. Fixed.

Comment: Try `Where(oi => oi.Order.idSite.Value == 1234)`.

Comment: @juharr that worked! If you wanna create an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I would if I could actually explain why it works.

Comment: @juharr likely because he's implicitly upcasting a `short?` to an `int?`. @SomeGuy if you declare `short s = 1234` and use that instead of using the literal `1234`, does it change things?

Comment: @CoryNelson No, it doesn't. Interestingly, even if I declare it as a short, entity still attempts the cast in SQL unless I use .Value.